# How can I restrict access to Linux server shared directories based on LDAP groups?

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, groups

Say I have a shared directory "SHARED" on my Linux server, and sub-directories like "REPORTS", "PROJECTS" etc.

"REPORTS" belongs to the group "MANAGERS".

Every client in the LAN (LDAP logged-in) have a NFS mount in their machines pointing to the server shared directory "SHARED", therefore they can view the sub-directories, but...

What I'm trying to do is:

**I want sub-directory "REPORTS" to be accessed only by clients whose users belongs to the same server group, eg.: If I'm in group "MANAGERS", then I can access directory "REPORTS".**

So far I created identical groups in server and client, same name, same UID, but no success. I'm getting "permission denied" errors.

It seems there's more to do in order to have a user logging in a client to be part of a group created on the server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to configure LDAP schema, populate LDAP server and then configure mount points with autofs on clients.

Please follow the detailed instructions at this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutofsLDAP).

Comment: Thank you, I'll read it.